# WSO2- Error Using Clone Mediator to send message to an endpoint

Tags: proxy, jms, wso2, clone

I am working on WSO2 proxy service that invokes a lot of other DSS services. My requirement is to send the response of one of the DSS service on to a jms queue and at the same time continue with the exsiting flow in the proxy service i.e. continue invoking and processing the other DSS services.

I need to get the response of Simple Product Service (sequence key -if4_simpleProduct) and send it back on to the queue, but after that continue with logic that is placed in the proxy service and sequence. I tried using CLONE Mediator for the same. But my prxy service flow stops after coming in to the CLONE Meditaor flow. Below is the snippet for proxy service and sequence.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="SPE_Payload"
    transports="jms" startOnLoad="true" trace="enable">
    <description />
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <transaction action="new" />
            <xslt key="StepToCommon" />
            <log level="full" />
            <enrich>
                <source type="body" clone="true" />
                <target type="property" property="MSG_PAYLOAD" />
            </enrich>

            <sequence key="if4_simpleProduct" />

            <filter xpath="boolean (//product/simpleProduct/altPrdCodes/pn_apc_id/text())">
                <enrich>
                    <source clone="true" xpath="//product/simpleProduct/altPrdCodes" />
                    <target type="property" property="ALT_PRDS" />
                </enrich>
                <sequence key="if4_alternateProducts" />
            </filter>
....
.....

<transaction action="commit" />
        </inSequence>

    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">test</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Given below is the code of for sequence while calling Simple Product Service

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="if4_simpleProduct"
    onError="myErrorHandlerSeq">
    <payloadFactory>
        <format>
            <p:O_SimpleProduct xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                <p:PC_STEP_SKU_ID>$1</p:PC_STEP_SKU_ID>
                </p:O_SimpleProduct>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg xmlns:m="http://wso2.org/services/product" evaluator="xml"
                expression="//product/simpleProduct/step_id/text()" />
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <header name="Action" value="urn:O_SimpleProduct" />
    <callout serviceURL="local://localhost/services/productEnrichment"
        action="urn:O_SimpleProduct" useServerConfig="true">
        <source xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="$body/child::*[fn:position()=1]" />
        <target xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="$body/child::*[fn:position()=1]" />
    </callout>
    <clone sequential="false">
<property name="RESPONSE" value="true" />
    <header name="To" action="remove" />
      <target>
      <endpoint>
            <address
                uri="jms:/step.IF04Output?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue" />
        </endpoint>
        </target>

      <target>
    <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ds="http://wso2.org/services/product"
        source="//ds:result/ds:set/ds:PC_STATUS/text()" regex="0">
        <then>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="STATUS"
                    value="************DONE INSERTING SIMPLE ATTRIBUTES***************" />
            </log>
        </then>
        <else>
            <log level="full" category="ERROR">
                <property name="STATUS"
                    value="************ERROR OCCURED WHILE INSERTING SIMPLE ATTRIBUTES. ROLLBACKING THE TRANSACTION***************" />
                <property name="PC_RP_ID" expression="get-property('GEN_RP_ID')" />
            </log>
            <transaction action="rollback" />
            <drop />
        </else>
    </filter>
    <property xmlns:ds="http://wso2.org/services/product" name="GEN_RP_ID"
        expression="//ds:result/ds:set/ds:PC_RP_ID/text()" />
    <enrich>
        <source type="property" clone="true" property="MSG_PAYLOAD" />
        <target type="body" />
    </enrich>
    </target>
</clone>
</sequence>
```

I am struggling with the issue since last two days. tried sing Clone meditior in several places. but it does not work. Could you please provide your suggestions soon as I have a demo to go tomorrow and I need to sort it out :(

Cheers,
Aanchal

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the part you are struggling;

```
<callout serviceURL="local://localhost/services/productEnrichment"
        action="urn:O_SimpleProduct" useServerConfig="true">
        <source xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="$body/child::*[fn:position()=1]" />
        <target xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="$body/child::*[fn:position()=1]" />
    </callout>
    <clone sequential="false">
<property name="RESPONSE" value="true" />
    <header name="To" action="remove" />
      <target>
      <endpoint>
            <address
                uri="jms:/step.IF04Output?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue" />
        </endpoint>
        </target>
```

Since your requirement is get response form one of the DS service and send that to queue..I think it fails because you are removing "To" header..Use callout mediator inside clone mediator's one of the "[Target](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Clone+Mediator#CloneMediator-Syntax)" configuration after sending to JMS queue drop the message there..In the other target, define your rest of the logic..